# Dynamically add a Edit text

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I want to add an edit text field to my app when i click a button, but i do not change the layout. Just add it below an existing one defined by the xml file.
Lets say i have a contacts app and if the user needs to add an extra field hit the button and creates one!
How to do that?

Comment: is it a finite number of textfields that can be opened? if it is you can just have these turn visible on firing the buttonClick event.

Comment: Just one at each button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is have those EditText's in a panel, i.e. group them in panels, then have a button, and on button click create an instance of an EditText and add it to the relevant panel. This way you are not limiting yourself to being only able to add one panel, but as much as the user would like to add.

Answer (score 5):

Keep an EditText item in your layout and set its visibility to **gone**.

```
 <EditText android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then on the onClick event of the button set visibility to **visible**.

or

You can add the EditText items programmatically.

Add a LinearLayout to your xml.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/editTextGroupLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

On button click event add EditText programmatically.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.editTextGroupLayout);
    EditText editTextView = new EditText(this);
    editTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);

    editTextView.setLayoutParams(params);

    linearLayout.addView(editTextView);
```

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you call the data from the webservice.

For example: 
description = Parser.getDescription;

In the xml layout:

```
 <Button android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="@string/ButtonClick"/>

 <EditText android:id="@+id/note" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Code:

```
        ButtonName  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.note);
        Data    = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.note);
        public void ButtonClick(View v){            
        description = Parser.getDescription;
        Data.settext(description);
    }
```