# Add EditText vertically programmatically

Tags: android

What should I put here?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    //Some code
}
```

I want N EditText like here : http://jsfiddle.net/7B8zB/1/

I tried to do `new EditText(this);` and `myLayout.addView(myEditText)`, but it rendered like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7B8zB/3/

My layout is linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Like this?:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Buddy Name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" >


            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Email Address"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Information" />


        </LinearLayout>
```

**Edit:**

```
 LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.editTextGroupLayout);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        EditText editTextView = new EditText(this);
        editTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);

        editTextView.setLayoutParams(params);

        linearLayout.addView(editTextView);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519040/dynamically-add-a-edit-text)

Comment: Yeah but I want to add them programmatically...

Comment: @Mageek see fida pasted your required code

Comment: the layoutparams you required LayoutParams

Comment: @Mageek: I also added the orientation code. Add new edittexts for your requirement.

Comment: @Mageek Great Clap Clap!!

Answer (score 1):

What you are using as container use LinearLayout if you are using that then set the orientation like this

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

by default it is Horizontal

Comment: Thanks it's a lot better, but now the TextEdit expands to be on the whole screen like that: http://jsfiddle.net/7B8zB/5/

Comment: It is not TextEdit it is editText and then you shall set LayoutParams and if it helps accept it

Comment: Yes TextEdit, it was a typo. But can you add how I should use `LayoutParams`?

Comment: @Mageek do search here there are too many questions already existing

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
<LinearLayout 

      android:orientation="vertical" 
      <EditText>           

       <EditText>                  

      <EditText>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText et;
LinearLayout ll;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

  ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_id);
  ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

 for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){
   et = new EditText(this);
    ll.addView(et);
}
```

This snippet code will create edittext dynamically.

Comment: ll.setOrientation(Vertical); directly vertical its wrong even gives compilation error there is nothing like **Vertical**

Comment: Set orientation like ln.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

Comment: Thanks Manishika for change the code